# Android erro - Must specify preferenceTheme in theme

Tags: android, android-layout

Criei um layout (preferences.xml) no diretório res/xml com base no PreferenceScreen.

Implementei uma classe derivada de PreferencesFragmentCompat

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat  
{
  @Override   
  public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);    
  }
}
```

Implementei a activity de preferências

```
public class PrefsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.prefs_activity);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragContent, new PrefsFragment());
    transaction.commit();
  }

}
```

Quando executo a activity o seguinte erro é exibido:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{PrefsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must
>   specify preferenceTheme in theme

Como faço para especificar o **preferenceTheme**?

Comment: Você declarou sua Activity no Manifest.xml?

Comment: Declarei! Me parece que quando usado um layout com <PreferenceScreen> tenho que declarar um tema diferente, só não sei como.

Comment: Qual é a *minSdkVersion*?

Comment: minSdkVersion 16

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo `res/values/styles.xml` acrescente

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
```

Se não alterou nada no arquivo gerado pelo Android Studio ficará assim:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

Se estiver a usar a *v7 Preference Support Library* aconselho que a substitua pela [v14 Preference Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v14-preference) porque na v7 existem ["problemas"](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183376) com o *preferenceTheme*.